# Login for different users not working in flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

So I've got a login form and I've got two user's in the users table one with a type student and the other is tutor. So when they log in it will take them to their own pages. But I've tested it but it doesn't work, it takes me to a page called None. So I want to know why it's doing this and what can I do to fix it??

Here is my code in the routes file:

```
def login():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
 if type=="student":
    return redirect(url_for('studentdashboard'))
elif type == "tutor":
    return redirect(url_for('tutordashboard'))
elif type == "admin":
    return redirect(url_for('admindashboard'))
form = LoginForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
    if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
        flash('Invalid username or password')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
    next_page= request.args.get('next')
    if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
     if type=="student":    next_page = url_for('studentdashboard')
     elif type=='tutor':    next_page = url_for('tutordashboard')
     elif type=='admin':    next_page = url_for('admindashboard')
    return redirect(next_page)
    return redirect(url_for('studentdashboard'))
return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

Here is my code in the models file :

```
class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'users'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
firstname = db.Column(db.String(50))
surname = db.Column(db.String(50))
username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
address = db.Column(db.String(100))
town = db.Column(db.String(100))
city = db.Column(db.String(100))
postcode = db.Column(db.String(7))
phone = db.Column(db.String(11))
workexperience = db.Column(db.String(100))
is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean,default=False)
type = db.Column(db.String(20))

def 
 __init__ (self, firstname, surname, username, email, password_hash, address, town, city, 
postcode, phone,workexperience,is_active,type):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.surname = surname
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password_hash = password_hash
        self.address = address
        self.town = town
        self.city = city
        self.postcode = postcode
        self.phone = phone
        self.workexperience = workexperience
        self.is_active = is_active
        self.type = type

def get_id(self):
        return self.id
def is_active(self):
        return self.is_active
def activate_user(self):
        self.is_active = True         
def get_username(self):
        return self.username
def get_type(self):
        return self.type
def login_required(role="ANY"):
 def wrapper(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated():
          return login_manager.unauthorized()
        if ((current_user.type != type) and (type != "ANY")):
            return login_manager.unauthorized()
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
    return wrapper
```

Here is the error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78wQZ.png)

Comment: It seems like `url_for` is not finding the view. Can you show the code with your views?

Comment: When I remove the if statements on this bit : if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
     if type=="student":    next_page = url_for('studentdashboard')
     elif type=='tutor':    next_page = url_for('tutordashboard')
     elif type=='admin':    next_page = url_for('admindashboard') and just have next_page= request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('studentdashboard') then it takes me to the studentdashboard but I want it to take me to the tutor dashboard if type is tutor

Comment: Am I miss reading, but I don't see how `type` is being referenced in the first conditionals within the login route? Shouldn't that be, `if current_user.type == "some type":` ?

Comment: I did that now and it only works for student but if I do more if statements for tutor and admin then it doesn't work it says 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: Nice! It looks like indentation is missing on the next 2 elif's? They should be inside the outer 'if current_user.is_authenticated:'?